# how do i skip TokenAuthentication class for only get requests django restframework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to have `TokenAuthentication` class for `post` request. But for `get` request I dont want this authentication class. How can I achieve this?

```
class EmailViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Email.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = EmailSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

What exactly happens here is that `TokenAuthentication` class get applied to all type of requests. But I want this class only for `POST` requests not for `GET` request.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can override the `get_authenticators` function:

```
def get_authenticators(self):
    """
    Instantiates and returns the list of authenticators that this view can use.
    """
    if self.request.method == "POST":
        return [TokenAuthentication()]

    return super(EmailViewSet, self).get_authenticators()
```

And, remove the `authentication_classes` from the view.

Comment: got error TypeError: get_authenticators() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Comment: which DRF version are you using?

Comment: Error is changed "AttributeError: 'EmailViewSet' object has no attribute 'request'"

Comment: Are you using `self.request.method`? Because, I used it on my machine and it works within this method.

Comment: for viewsets.ModelViewSet its not working. May be you used it for view only

Comment: Now I see, you can not use this on ModelViewSet. It is really strange that DRF has done it like that :(